# In "Common module settings" / "Availability" there are only 2 options

Tags: moodle

In a moodle course (v4.0) I have added a `Page`. In page's settings in `Common module settings` in Availability there are only 2 options:

- Show on course page
- Hide from students

[image]

However, here https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Common_module_settings it says that a 3rd option should appear  **Make available but not shown on course page**. Why I am not seeing this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have "Allow stealth activities" enabled? The default is disabled

Go to Site administration > Advanced features

See https://docs.moodle.org/400/en/Stealth_activities